# Application keep crashing when deploying to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We are trying to deploy application to Bluemix using the CF command `cf push -f manifest.yml` and below is the attached `yml` file

```
applications:
- name: service_name_v1.0
  memory: 1GB
  buildpack: liberty-for-java
  instances: 1
  path: /Users/admin/Apps/wlp-cb/usr/servers/defaultServer/defaultServer.zip
  domains: 
    - my.bluemix.org

  hosts:
    - my-service-space
  timeout: 180
```

> DEA/2
>
> Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
>
> May 4, 2017 10:10:55 AM
>
> API/0
>
> App instance exited with guid ae937fbe-d88f-48d5-b985-12b3b71b3b8c payload: {“cc_partition”=>”default”, “droplet”=>”ae937fbe-d88f-48d5-b985-12b3b71b3b8c”, “version”=>”94e28b95-27d3-4554-b99b-11d453f40e7f”, “instance”=>”9b723df2d462441caa352e3337b4e230”, “index”=>0, “reason”=>”CRASHED”, “exit_status”=>0, “exit_description”=>”failed to accept connections within health check timeout”, “crash_timestamp”=>1493917855}
>
> May 4, 2017 10:10:55 AM
>
> API/1
>
> App instance exited with guid ae937fbe-d88f-48d5-b985-12b3b71b3b8c payload: {“cc_partition”=>”default”, “droplet”=>”ae937fbe-d88f-48d5-b985-12b3b71b3b8c”, “version”=>”94e28b95-27d3-4554-b99b-11d453f40e7f”, “instance”=>”9b723df2d462441caa352e3337b4e230”, “index”=>0, “reason”=>”CRASHED”, “exit_status”=>0, “exit_description”=>”failed to accept connections within health check timeout”, “crash_timestamp”=>1493917855}

Comment: Does your application start successfully on your local machine? Did you check its logs on Bluemix?

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that your server isn't listening on the right port.

I recommend deploying the Liberty Buildpack [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/liberty-for-java?taxonomyNavigation=apps) and subsequently downloading the source code. This should give you a working Liberty app with the correct manifest to push code to Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

You list the path to the target artifact as a zip file and the build pack probably does not recognize that artifact type. Try changing it to an executable jar or a war or ear file.